# Install R package stuck at g++ -std=gnu++11?

Tags: r

I am installing R package `readr` in Ubuntu 18.04 and stuck at below line. It didn't report any error but has been stuck like this for more than a hour.

```
install.packages("readr", dependencies=T)
* installing *source* package ‘rprojroot’ ...
** package ‘rprojroot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (rprojroot)
* installing *source* package ‘readr’ ...
** package ‘readr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-t3diwe/r-base-3.6.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Collector.cpp -o Collector.o
```

Some suggestions? Or other way to get around?

Comment: Can you try with a binary option `add-apt-repository -y ppa:marutter/c2d4u3.5;
apt-get -y update;
#apt-get install -y r-cran-readr
#or 
apt-get install -y r-cran-tidyverse`

Comment: It works! Thanks @akrun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is binary installation either from a shell script or from terminal directly

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:marutter/c2d4u3.5
apt-get -y update; 
apt-get install -y r-cran-readr 
#or get most of the packages of tidyverse
apt-get install -y r-cran-tidyverse
```